# task scheduler - Execute and pause

Tags: windows, tasks

I am struggling with a task in the task scheduler. I want to have a script get executed every 5 minutes (which works fine) but if it is executed, the task should stop for at least 12 hours.

That is the tricky part.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So you want a task after 5 minutes then run again 12 hours later? Your question is not clear.

Comment: no i want to start a script every 5 minutes to check if a device is online. if it is online, the script executes something. After this, the '5 minute check' should get delayed for 12 hours.

Comment: I think the only way is if the device is online run the script. The script needs to do whatever it is already doing, then delete the current task, then create a new task to run every five minutes starting 12 hours later. See [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) for how to do this in a script file.

Comment: @DavidPostill Correct me if I'm wrong but couldn't the same task be modified by the script itself using `schtasks /change /RI 720 ...` and the task interval be increased?

Comment: @Vinayak You are correct. The link I gave says `SCHTASKS /Change [Connect_Options] {[/RU username] [/RP password] [/TR taskrun]} /TN taskname` but `schtasks /change /?` gives the full list.